# How to avoid CORS Error in Vuejs running in a docker Container?

Tags: docker, vue.js, axios, cors, containers

I have a Vue Frontend inside a docker container which connects to a Spring-boot backend in another container. The backend gets its data from a MongoDB (also in a container).
When I build my Vue frontend into a docker container, and try to get data from the Database, I get a CORS error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8010/persons' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My backend is running in a docker container with port 8010 published and my Vue frontend in a container with port 8080. Allow-cross-origin is already set in my backend.

this is the dockerfile in my frontend:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["http-server", "dist"]
```

and build the image with:

```
docker build -t frontend .
```

and

```
docker run -d -it -p 8080:8080 --name frontend frontend
```

So in Vue i set axios to:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8010/";

axios.defaults.headers.get["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.get["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
```

and make this request:

```
axios.get("/persons").then(res => {
        if (res.data.length === 0) {
          console.log("No Persons found!", res.data);
        }
        console.info("ready", res.data);
        for (let i in res.data) {
          this.persons.push(res.data[i]);
        }
      });
```

In my Spring-boot backend i already allow cross-origin access.

And in development mode everything works, because I can proxy the request inside the vue.config.js file with

```
devServer: {
  proxy: "http://localhost:8010"
  }
```

and i my browser i also can connect to my backend and to swagger. Just the vue app doesn't find the backend.
What is the problem there?
How can i avoid the cors error and reach my backend?

*sorry for my bad english*